# How to pass functions for traits implemented with lifetimes?

Tags: rust

Rust beginner here. I have this "binary calculator" that uses a couple of types..

```
pub enum Bit { Off, On };
pub struct Binary([Bit; 64]);
```

Ignoring everything else that is implemented for them, I overloaded the operators for the `Binary` like so...

```
impl Add for Binary {
    type Output = Binary;

    /// Basic implementation of full addition circuit
    fn add(self, other: Binary) -> Binary {
        ...
    }
}

... Div, Sub, and Mul
```

... where each operator consumes the `Binary`s passed to them.  I was then able to define a set of public functions that took care of converting, calling, and printing everything how I wanted to...

```
pub fn add(x: i64, y: i64) -> Calc {
    execute(Binary::add, x, y)
}

pub fn subtract(x: i64, y: i64) -> Calc {
    execute(Binary::sub, x, y)
}

...

fn execute(f: fn(Binary, Binary) -> Binary, x: i64, y: i64) -> Calc {
    let bx = Binary::from_int(x);
    println!("{:?}\n{}\n", bx, x);

    let by = Binary::from_int(y);
    println!("{:?}\n{}\n", by, y);

    let result = f(bx, by);
    println!("{:?}", result);

    result.to_int()
}
```

### problem

This worked, but the operations consumed the `Binary`s, which I didn't actually want. So instead, I implemented the traits using references instead...

```
impl<'a, 'b> Add<&'b Binary> for &'a Binary {
    type Output = Binary;

    /// Basic implementation of full addition circuit
    fn add(self, other: &'b Binary) -> Binary {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, though, I cannot figure out how to pass those functions to `execute` as I did before. For example, `execute(Binary::div, x, y)` is giving the following error.

```
error[E0277]: cannot divide `types::binary::Binary` by `_`
  --> src/lib.rs:20:13
   |
20 |     execute(Binary::div, x, y)
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^ no implementation for `types::binary::Binary / _`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::ops::Div<_>` is not implemented for
    `types::binary::Binary`
```

How can I pass that specific implementation with lifetimes? I assume that I need to update the signature for `execute` too, like...

```
fn execute<'a, 'b>(f: fn(&'a Binary, &'b Binary) -> Binary, ...
```

But I wind up also seeing...

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:20:13
   |
20 |     execute(Binary::div, x, y)
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected reference, found struct `types::binary::Binary`
   |
   = note: expected type `fn(&types::binary::Binary, &types::binary::Binary) -> types::binary::Binary`
          found type `fn(types::binary::Binary, _) -> <types::binary::Binary as std::ops::Div<_>>::Output {<types::binary::Binary as std::ops::Div<_>>::div}`
```

Being a complete beginner, I was able to follow all the error messages that got me to the "working" point (where operations consumed the values), but now I'm a bit out of my league, I think.

Comment: Why can't you just modify `Binary` to derive `Copy` or `Clone` and then use the clone of them in `execute` and forget about lifetimes entirely? It's impossible to pass a `&Binary` or `&'a Binary` or really anything that isn't a `Binary` to a function (The `add` or `mul` or whatever function defined in the appropriate trait) that explicitly states that it takes `fn add(self, ..)`, because it's meant to consume `self`. Anyway, I'm not posting an answer because I'm not sure that I'm qualified to write an answer under lifetimes yet. Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: *"Please correct me if I'm wrong!"* Believe me, I would be the *last* person who is able to make any corrections on anything Rust-related! *"It's impossible ... because it's meant to consume self."* I think that makes sense, you're probably right that the best thing to do is use `Copy` or `Clone`.. The whole `execute` thing is probably bad, too...

Comment: Yeah, the point of `std::ops::add` etc is really just syntactical sugar for `a + b`, I don't understand why you are passing the functions around

Comment: Well... Passing them around means I can handle the conversions & printing boilerplate in a single place... but mostly it's just a "see if and how I can" kind of learning exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an exemplary implementation for addition (I made some assumptions regarding the return type of `execute` and others, you'd have to adapt this if my assumptions are wrong):

```
use std::ops::Add;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Bit { Off, On }
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Binary([Bit; 32]);

impl Binary {
    fn to_int(&self) -> i64 {unimplemented!()}
    fn from_int(n: i64) -> Self {unimplemented!()}
}

impl<'a, 'b> Add<&'b Binary> for &'a Binary {
    type Output = Binary;
    fn add(self, other: &'b Binary) -> Binary {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

pub fn add(x: i64, y: i64) -> i64 {
   execute(|a, b| a+b, x, y)
}

fn execute(f: fn(&Binary, &Binary) -> Binary, x: i64, y: i64) -> i64 {
    let bx = Binary::from_int(x);
    println!("{:?}\n{}\n", bx, x);

    let by = Binary::from_int(y);
    println!("{:?}\n{}\n", by, y);

    let result = f(&bx, &by);
    println!("{:?}", result);

    result.to_int()
}
```

Note that within `execute`, you'd have to call `f(&bx, &by)` (i.e. borrow them instead of consuming).

However: I wondered why you chose to have `fn(&Binary, &Binary) -> Binary` as argument type instead of making `execute` generic over `F`, constraining `F` to be a callable:

```
fn execute<F>(f: F, x: i64, y: i64) -> i64
    where
        F: Fn(&Binary, &Binary) -> Binary,
{
    let bx = Binary::from_int(x);
    println!("{:?}\n{}\n", bx, x);

    let by = Binary::from_int(y);
    println!("{:?}\n{}\n", by, y);

    let result = f(&bx, &by);
    println!("{:?}", result);

    result.to_int()
}
```

This way, you are a bit more flexible (you can e.g. pass closures capturing variables in their scope).

Comment: Oh nice, I wish it had occurred to me to use closures, but that works perfectly! Also: "I wondered why you chose..." Definitely the beginner in me.. Looking at your suggestion, how does using the generic w/ constraint differ from defining the argument type as I did?

Comment: @kevlarr `Fn` is a trait and therefore unsized, and can't be passed around in the stack (function memory), on the other hand, `fn` is a function pointer, and therefore has a size and can be passed around like as if it were just a regular reference,